# SQL - Like Excel sumif

Tags: sql, excel, aggregate-functions, sumifs

I have tried looking for a solution to this, but have probably been missing the solution to this problem that's nagging me at the moment.

How do I sum values from one column where rows in another column is alike? In Excel I know of the sumif() function that gives me perfect results, but here in SQL I can't...

I have following columns - I want to add all 'OrderQty' rows where 'Article' are identical:

```
Article                     Order       OrderQty 
5710986678708               931714523    2,00 
5710986678708               931714554    2,00 
5710986678708               931714532    2,00 
5710986678708               931714515    2,00 
5710987052460               954466387    1,00 
5710987052460               954466405    1,00 
5710987052460               954466404    1,00 
5710987052460               931714450    2,00 
5710987052460               931714482    2,00 
5710987052460               931714472    2,00 
5710987052460               931714474    1,00 
5710986678692               954466466    2,00 
5710986678692               954466483    1,00 
5710986678692               954466484    2,00 
5710986678692               954466464    1,00 
5710986678692               954466501    1,00 
5710986678692               954466473    1,00
```

My output should be like this:

```
Article                     Order    OrderQty    TotalOrdered 
5710986678708               931714523    2,00    8,00 
5710986678708               931714554    2,00    8,00 
5710986678708               931714532    2,00    8,00 
5710986678708               931714515    2,00    8,00 
5710987052460               954466387    1,00    10,00 
5710987052460               954466405    1,00    10,00 
5710987052460               954466404    1,00    10,00 
5710987052460               931714450    2,00    10,00 
5710987052460               931714482    2,00    10,00 
5710987052460               931714472    2,00    10,00 
5710987052460               931714474    1,00    10,00 
5710986678692               954466466    2,00    8,00 
5710986678692               954466483    1,00    8,00 
5710986678692               954466484    2,00    8,00 
5710986678692               954466464    1,00    8,00 
5710986678692               954466501    1,00    8,00 
5710986678692               954466473    1,00    8,00
```

In Excel I would do - assuming 'Article' is column A:
=Sumif('Article';'A2';'OrderQty')

I have tried with a Case statement, but in the 'TotalOrdered' column it returns the same quantity as the 'OrderQty' - on line level rather than summing up on article level.

Any help?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Using ANSI standard window functions is the simplest:

```
select t.*, sum(OrderQty) over (partition by ArticleId) as TotalOrdered
from mytable t;
```

If your database doesn't support this functionality, you can still do this.  You can use `group by` and `join` or a correlated subquery, for instance.  Here is an example with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(OrderQty)
        from mytable t2
        where t2.ArticleId = t.ArticleId
       ) as TotalOrdered
from mytable t;
```